# How to get data from Firebase (Firestore) into list of models in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My Firebase looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMRE1.png).

I have `QuestionModel` class:

```
class QuestionModel{
  String question;
  String option1;
  String option2;
  String option3;
  String option4;
  bool answered;
  String questionType;
}
```

I want to get all questions from this form (every form has ID) and make `List<QuestionModel>`.

This is how I make `QuestionModel` from `DataSnapshot`:

```
QuestionModel getQuestionModelFromDatasnapshot(
    DocumentSnapshot questionSnapshot) {
  QuestionModel questionModel = QuestionModel();

  questionModel.question = questionSnapshot.data["question"];

  questionModel.option1 = questionSnapshot.data["ans1"];
  questionModel.option2 = questionSnapshot.data["ans2"];
  questionModel.option3 = questionSnapshot.data["ans3"];
  questionModel.option4 = questionSnapshot.data["ans4"];

  questionModel.questionType = questionSnapshot.data["questionType"];

  questionModel.answered = false;

  return questionModel;
}
```

I know how to make list of Widgets using `ListView` and `FutureBuilder` (that's the way I can get whole questionary in one view), but I want to know how to make a list of `QuestionModel` so I could use this data in other classes (my final goal is to make questionary where every question have its own view).

How to do that?

If that is not possible, another ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: use PageView

Find out more about PageView:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html